# Sync samba users with debian users

Tags: debian, samba, file-sharing, smb-conf

I've a machine running Debian 9 in which I've installed samba.
I'm trying to sync the debian users credential with the samba users credential.

My smb.conf is this:

```
[global] 
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  server string = Samba Server %v 
  netbios name = debian 
  security = user 
  dns proxy = no
  log level = 3
  server role = standalone server 
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  obey pam restrictions = yes
  unix password sync = yes
  passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
  passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
  pam password change = yes
  map to guest = bad user

[UserAuthRequired]
  comment = User authentication required
  path = /mnt/ExternalDisk1Master/AuthRequiredFolder
  valid users = @samba_users
  force group = samba_users
  create mask = 0660
  directory mask = 0771
  writable = yes
```

With this configuration if I change the user password on Linux, the samba credential doesn't sync properly (samba continues to works with the old password).
Can anyone give me a hint?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is more than a year old, but I feel like it deserves an answer. The unix password sync setting requires a careful read of the documentation. It allows for SMB password changes to update the UNIX password.

According to

> man smb.conf

```
   unix password sync (G)

       This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to synchronize the
       UNIX password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in
       the smbpasswd file is changed. If this is set to yes the program
       specified in the passwd program parameter is called AS ROOT - to allow
       the new UNIX password to be set without access to the old UNIX password
       (as the SMB password change code has no access to the old password
       cleartext, only the new).

       This option has no effect if samba is running as an active directory
       domain controller, in that case have a look at the password hash gpg key
       ids option and the samba-tool user syncpasswords command.

       Default: unix password sync = no
```

Note that it refers to smbpasswd file being changed, not vice versa.

If you can find a way to have this work in reverse, or better yet, to work without a Samba user, please let us all know.